# Apache not displaying jpg images just an x

Tags: apache, tomcat

Utilizing Tomcat 5.5.26 (yes old version but application needs to be upgraded to be compatible with newer version)
The Tomcat app and apache have been relocated to a new server and all works properly except for the displaying of compressed jpg images from a mount.  Just an x appears instead of the image.  When copying the path from the x'd image location is correct (and is viewable on the mount).  I've compare httpd and application.properties among other files against the original that has been displaying images correctly for years and they seem to match.  Any tomcat professionals have any thoughts?

Comment: I won't call myself a professional but I have some limited experience. Did you load the WAR file onto the new server? Not just the related web files.

Comment: Thank you.  I did.  With the exception of some of repointing to a new database location (not related to the images) it is the same WAR.

Comment: Again since my experience is limited I may not be of much help with the troubleshooting. However, you can always join the Internet Relay Chat for Apache Tomcat where some of the developers sit and assist users. You can find your way to the chat via http://tomcat.apache.org/irc.html

Comment: thank you again and I'll take a shot there.

Comment: falconspy thank you for the direction.  I found my answer in that chat.   Port issue

Comment: Cheers! Glad you resolved your issue